# System.ServiceModel.FaultException' en mscorlib.dll c# que puedo hacer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, webservice

**Mi error es el siguiente
valor de tiempo de espera caducado. El período de tiempo de espera expiró antes de obtener una conexión del grupo. Esto puede suceder porque todas las conexiones de la agrupación estaban en uso y se alcanzó el máximo tamaño del grupo".**

**System.ServiceModel.FaultException' en mscorlib.dll NO puedo solucionar este error**

en este boton mando a llamar mi servicio que esta dentro de una funcion

```
`private  void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { DateTime dts = DateTime.Now;
            //CONEXION
            label1.Text = "Inicio: " + dts;
            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
            MessageBox.Show("Conectado a oracle");
            con.Open();
            // CONSULTA SQL Y MOSTRADO DE REGISTROS EN EL DAYA GRIDVIEW
            var inicio = "TO_TIMESTAMP(sysdate)";
            var final = "CAST(sysdate AS TIMESTAMP)";
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Prueba WHERE Fecha between " + inicio + "AND " + final + " AND motivo not in ('PRUEBA/LLAMADA DE PRUEBA') order by FECHA ";
            
            OracleDataAdapter adp = new OracleDataAdapter(sql, con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
          
            
            adp.Fill(dt);
            dgvTelefonos.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dgvTelefonos.DataSource = dt;
            dgvTelefonos.Refresh();

            var total_registros = dgvTelefonos.RowCount;
            label2.Text = "Total de registros : " + total_registros;
            

            // RECORRIDO DE FILAS Y PASADO DE DATOS A EL SERVICO WEB 
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvTelefonos.Rows)
            {
                oWs.Start();
                timer2.Enabled = true;
                Form2 f = new Form2();
              
                var contar = row.Index + 1;

                richTextBox1.Text = " ";
                // i el numero de columnas

                FECHA_HORA_INICIO_LLAMADA = row.Cells["FECHA_HORA_INICIO_LLAMADA"].Value.ToString();
                FECHA_LLAMADA = row.Cells["FECHA_LLAMADA"].Value.ToString();
                richTextBox1.Text ="Inicio de registro"+dts+
 "CARGANDO REGISTRO : " +  contar.ToString() + " DE : " + total_registros.ToString() + Environment.NewLine
                   + "FECHA_HORA_INICIO_LLAMDA :" + FECHA_HORA_INICIO_LLAMADA + " " + Environment.NewLine
                       + "FECHA_LLAMADA :" + FECHA_LLAMADA + " " + Environment.NewLine 
                      ;
 //aqui esta la llamada a mi funcion
                f.Show();
              f.pasado(DateTime.Parse(FECHA_HORA_INICIO_LLAMADA).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), DateTime.Parse(FECHA_LLAMADA).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy "));
                f.Close();

              

                if (total_registros == contar)
                {
                    DateTime dtl = DateTime.Now;
                   
                    label3.Text = "Fecha fin : " + dtl ;
                    
                }
            }
            timer2.Stop();
            con.Close();

        }
`
```

aqui esta mi funcion donde declaro el data set con mi servicio

```
`public void pasado(string fECHA_HORA_INICIO_LLAMADA, string fECHA_LLAMADA)
        {

            try
            {
                WebS.WebService1SoapClient Ws = new WebS.WebService1SoapClient();
                
                DataSet d1 = Ws.prueba(@"REPi2", @"451", @"CP",
               DateTime.Parse(fECHA_HORA_INICIO_LLAMADA).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), DateTime.Parse(fECHA_LLAMADA).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
                dataGridView1.DataSource = d1.Tables[0];
            }
            catch (FaultException Ex)
            {

            }

        }}
`
```

mi conexion es la siguente

```
 `//Mi conexion es esta
    string constr = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION="
            + "(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.16.2.20)(PORT=1685)))"
            + "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=a0252200)));"
            + "User Id=prueba;Password=asds;"
           ;`
```

Comment: no, Tengo como 300 datos

Comment: y falla cuando agrega los primeros 100

Comment: falla cuando agrega los primeros 100 adonde? por favor, se claro con tu problema... tene en cuenta que solo vemos 10 lineas de codigo, no tenemos ni idea de todo lo que pasa alrededor...

Comment: despues de esos 100 me manda  a ese error

Comment: Bueno cuando agrega a la base de datos sqlserver

Comment: eso es lo que hace el servicio web que tengo por eso lo mando a llamar para hacer un respaldo a slq server

Comment: y donde estas agregando a la base de datos? y donde estas obteniendo los datos? en tu codigo no se entiende ni el orden, ni que es cada cosa, ni donde estas agregando algo a una base de datos... Entiendo que necesites ayuda, pero tene en cuenta que para ayudar necesitamos saber todo lo que pasa... El error, por si solo, dice que tu conexion tardo en responder.. puede ser por cualquier cosa.. hasta el problema podria estar en tu ws... si queres una respuesta, tene en cuenta de poner toda la informacion que nos ayude a ayudarte...

Comment: hago la consulta, en el boton, es a oracle y los muestro en un data grid que se menciona en el codigo, en el foreach  a los valores mostrados anteriormente les agrego un string para que los guarde y finalmente paso esos parametros al servicio web para que se inserten en sqlserver  DataSet d1 = Ws.prueba(@"REPi2", @"451", @"CP",
               DateTime.Parse(fECHA_HORA_INICIO_LLAMADA).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), DateTime.Parse(fECHA_LLAMADA).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
                dataGridView1.DataSource = d1.Tables[0];

Comment: entonces el problema es el webservice

Comment: Lo seria si no funcionara Aparte, pero si funciona solo, digamos que si inserto en el web service desde la url si se puede y no manda ningun error

Pero al momento de implementarlo en este formulario nuevo pasa eso,

Abria alguna otra forma de Hacer lo que quiero?

Comment: vos mismo lo decis...tu programa no hace una insercion.. hace 100 en cuestion de milisegundos... probaste eso?

Comment: en sql Hay un procedimiento almacenado que si no existe inserta y si existe actualiza

Comment: ok voy a dejar aca porque se hace largo y no nos entendemos... no se que tiene que ver sql server aca, pq el problema es un web service que no contesta.. y por algo no contesta...